# How to evaluate Python Regex correctly?

Tags: python, regex

There is a list of strings and I need to manipulate those which do not end in ",\d\d" (comma followed by two digits).

So I went to https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html and tried out some code, put everything in my own function and out came something like this, however it doesn't match anything.

```
def translatePrice(text):
    text = str(text)
    text = text.strip()
    if (re.search(r',\d\d$', text) == None):
        print "Error in ", text
    return text
```

I am pretty sure that my regex raw string is formatted in a way that python can understand it. What I am not sure about is if the rest of the code is any good. I also found "endswith('xy')" but that doesn't help me that much since I need to match any pair of digits.

Here is some examples of how my input strings look like:

- `25` outputs `Error in 25`
- `25,25` outputs `25,25`
- `1` outputs `Error in 1`
- `1,0` outputs `Error in 1,0`
- `1,00` outputs `1,00`

Comment: Do you need a regexp? Any reason you don't want to do `text[-2:].isdigit() and text[-3] == ','`?

Comment: I assume the `return` is meant to be indented (and the semicolon serves no purpose), but other than that, this should work.

Comment: Try this [awesome online regex tester/explainer](https://regex101.com/#python)

Comment: The main reason would be that I was not aware of .isdigit(). Going to check that out. Also I fixed the indent and the semicolon. This whole Python thing is really new to me, but loving it already.

Comment: AFAICT, the code you showed is working properly. When you say that it's not matching anything, how did you verify that? Have you also verified that `text` is what you think it is *before* applying the regex?

Comment: ... Does `text` actually represent a price? What type exactly are you expecting it to have on the way in? What are you going to do exactly when the string doesn't match, and what does the comma etc. mean?

Comment: I know we see a lot of questions where regex is the wrong tool for the job, but for once, this seems like a fairly appropriate use of it. (Maybe not *strictly* necessary, but definitely not inappropriate.)

Comment: Piece of advice: drop the `== None` part and the unnecessary paranetheses. Just do `if re.search(r',\d\d$', text):`.

Comment: @jpmc26: I agree with the paranetheses, but `== None` completely changes the meaning of the `if`, so I wouldn't just drop it. I'd change it to `is None`, but `== None` is acceptable for me.

Comment: @user: I cannot reproduce your problem, `re.search(r'\d\d', s) == None` works for me, what is your problem?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus For `re.search`, no, it doesn't change the meaning of the `if`. `re.search` returns `None` if nothing was found and an object (which will not be falsy) if it finds a match. There are times when I do include explicit `is None` checks, but only when I want to explicitly prevent falsy objects from triggering the particular branch of code.

Comment: @jpmc26: I mean, you can get rid of it, but you can't just drop it -- you would have to change the condition, or restructure the code.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus No, you wouldn't. Not for `re.search`. The two are strictly equivalent because of the behavior of `re.search`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98263/discussion-between-gingerplusplus-and-jpmc26).

Comment: My apologies. I forgot a `not`. It should be `if not re.search(r',\d\d$', text):`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex:

```
    text = text.strip()
    if len(text) < 3:
       return False
    if  text[-3] == "," and text[-2:].isdigit():
       # all good
```

Comment: Thanks, after reviewing what .isdigit() does, my solution looks pretty similar to your code.

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't match anything.

Huh? I cannot reproduce your problem, your code works fine for me for all example input you provided:

```
>>> 'Good' if re.search(r',\d\d$', '25') else 'Bad'
'Bad'
>>> 'Good' if re.search(r',\d\d$', '25,25') else 'Bad'
'Good'
>>> 'Good' if re.search(r',\d\d$', '1') else 'Bad'
'Bad'
>>> 'Good' if re.search(r',\d\d$', '1,0') else 'Bad'
'Bad'
>>> 'Good' if re.search(r',\d\d$', '1,00') else 'Bad'
'Good'
```